# Can I get a Mercurial with Subversion subrepository to automatically check out?

Tags: svn, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I've set up a Mercurial repository that has a subversion subrepository.  I've configured an `.hgsub` file so that Mercurial is aware of that repository. However, I was expecting that Mercurial could trigger an `svn update` automatically whenever I did a pull on the repository.

Is this possible with Mercurial subversion repositories?  If not, what's the advantage of having the `.hgsub` file at all as opposed to placing that subdirectory in `.hgignore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial does not automatically pull/update subrepos.  From [`hg help subrepos`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/subrepos):

> Subrepos do not automatically track the latest changeset of their
>   sources. Instead, they are updated to the changeset that corresponds
>   with the changeset checked out in the top-level changeset. This is so
>   developers always get a consistent set of compatible code and
>   libraries when they update.
>
> Thus, updating subrepos is a manual process. Simply check out target
>   subrepo at the desired revision, test in the top-level repo, then commit
>   in the parent repository to record the new combination.

Placing the repo in `.hgignore` would not allow you to track which version of the subrepo is compatible/tested with each version of the parent.

In SVN terms, this is similar to create an `svn:external` link which is bound to a specific SVN revision.

Comment: The problem with this is that if a new user were to clone the hg repository, the initial pull would fail since there would be no svn repository as of yet to match up with the .hgsub file.  Instead new users must first add the subrepository before they can add the main repository.  Is there any clean way to handle this?

Comment: The only user that needs to manually clone the subrepo is the one who creates the subrepo link.  Once `.hgsub` is pushed, the next user to clone or pull will automatically get the subrepo.  When `clone` or `pull` encounter a changeset containing subrepos, it attempts to pull the specified subrepos and update them to the appropriate state.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  When I tried this with TortoiseHG it failed and I didn't think to try on the command line.  I suspect this is a bug with TortoiseHG.